# Views in Doctrine ORM

Tags: doctrine

I encountered a problem dealing with views in Doctrine.

I have the following view in my database:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
                        ->select('c.id, c.name, m.id, m.name, m.status, 
                                  m.modified, m.entered, m.accountid')
                        ->from('Category c')
                        ->leftJoin('c.Mailing m');
$view = new Doctrine_View($q, 'view_mailings');
$q->execute(array(), Doctrine::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

The result comprises of all records. However I need to fetch a subset
based on different value for accountid and ordered by different
columns. How can I achieve this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

A different solution could be creating a schema for the view inside config/doctrine/ like this:

```
objective:
  tableName: objective
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer
    zone:
      type: string(50)
    province:
      type: string(30)
    city:
      type: string(100)
    population:
      type: integer
    city_obj_id:
      type: integer
    clinic_number:
      type: integer
    clinic_obj:
      type: integer
    comments:
      type: string(255)
```

and then put a objective_view.sql inside data/sql/ like this:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS objective;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS objective;
CREATE VIEW objective AS
    SELECT
    c.id as id,
    z.name as zone,
    p.name as province,
    c.name as city,
    cs.amount as population,
    co.id as city_obj_id,
    co.clinic_num as clinic_number,
    co.clinic_obj as clinic_obj,
    co.comments as comments

    FROM
    city c left join city_objective co on co.city_id = c.id
    left join city_census cs on (cs.city_id = c.id and cs.year = 2009)
    left join province p on p.id = c.province_id
    left join zone z on z.id = p.zone_id;
```

In this way the objective table will get populated with updated data and you can execute query on it to get relevant info with ease.

Comment: I can see that the question had been posted quiet long ago! How did you deal with it? or Have you found any other better ways to deal with doctrine views?

Comment: How does the `objective_view.sql` get executed? The `insert-sql` task doesn't seem to do it...

Comment: @PeterTaylor: if you do `symfony doctrine:build --all --and-load` it will execute all the sql scripts inside data/sql/ folder...

Answer (score 1):

You are just executing the query $q, without using the view you have created.

Comment: Sorry, but there is not much sense in your answer. If I wanted to use straight query, I wouldn't bother at all to make views in the database.